# Как ставить ударение в слове "паж"?

Tags: фонетика

Как ставить ударение в слове "паж": "-пажем" или "пажом"?

Comment: Пажем или пажом склонение существительных 2 склонения .Подчиняется общему правилу

Comment: Вы уточняете свой вопрос или отвечаете на него?)))

Answer (score 1):

Паж
Паж, пажа́, -о́м; мн. пажи́, -е́й. (Словарь ударений)

Answer (score 1):

во всех падежах, кроме именительного, ударение падает на последний слог. В тв.падеже - -ом, ведь в конце слова "паж" стоит твёрдая согласная, и ударный слог к тому же.